# jQuery; Submit Form if Required Fields Filled in and Other Combinations Are True

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, submit

I have a form with dozens of fields. Some are required, some are not. With the fields that are required, I have added `class="required"` to the item

I found this snippet of code and was wondering how to adjust it

```
$('#form').submit (function() {
  if(formValidated())
    return true;
  return false;
});
```

I only want to submit the form where all fields that have the `class="required"` are filled out i.e. not empty. How would I do this?

In addition, I have many radio buttons and if '**Yes**' is selected (Defaults to '**No**'), then a textarea appears with something similar to the below

```
$("#rb_name_yes").click(function(){  
  $('#textarea_name').show();
});
```

I guess I could change this to

```
$("#rb_name_yes").click(function(){  
  $('#textarea_name').show();
  $(this).addClass('required');
});
```

and change the code to hide the textarea to

```
$("#rb_name_no").click(function(){  
  $('#textarea_name').hide();
  $(this).removeClass('required');
});
```

Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is jQuery.validation. You'll find information about it on the jQuery site.

Comment: Do you mean the plugin or has jQuery got something similar built into it?

Comment: I mean the plugin. The documentation, however, is on the main jQuery site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for a complex solution like the validate plugin you could use something like:

```
function formValidated( $form ){
    var empty = 0;
    $(':input,:select', $form).each(function(){
        if( !$(this).val() )
            empty++;
    });
    return (( empty==0 ) ? true : false );
}
```

It's no flawless tho, it could be improved.
Hope it helps.

Comment: How would I go about it, using the validate plugin? I'd want to add a class to the field item rather than add text to the side

Comment: $("#myformname").validate();

I tried that but adds text . I don't need the text, instead I want to do what it does but not to add the text only the class name to be updated to "error" but can't fathom out how to do this

Comment: This is custom made, no validate plugin involved.

Comment: "I only want to submit the form where all fields that have the class="required" are filled out i.e. not empty. How would I do this?" my code does exactly that, you just need to change the selector to match your requirements.